# Building XNA solution (in VS2010) freezes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna-4.0, freeze

I've encountered a problem where part way through building a solution, VS 2010 becomes locked and never returns. If I build individual projects one by one it works so the building of project is working. The solution contains XNA projects for various platforms and winforms libraries. This did work up until a point but have found no explanation for the sudden freezing.

I've uninstalled all of my plugins to see if that helps but no difference.

In task manager, VS2010 is busy doing something as it's using CPU and consuming memory >1GB.

Comment: Do you have a spritefont with a full (or almost full) unicode character set or other big resources your content pipeline has to convert?

Comment: I have a music track included but it's not big, so to speak. Can I not add a music track to the content project?

Comment: Does it work (better) if you exclude the music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a significant amount of time/removed music to sort it.